# How do I preserve the image detail when making a texture? Unity

Tags: unity

I have made a texture, set its shader to 'legacy shaders/diffuse' and dragged some images I like into the texture. When using the texture the images don't look as detailed as before. How can I overcome this?
[image]

[image]

As you can see, it is just one colour, there are no dark spots anywhere.

Comment: The object's UV coordinates are likely not correctly configured.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like whoever created that icosphere in their 3d modeling program forgot to properly set up texture coordinates (also called UV coordinates). These are coordinates which get assigned to each corner of each polygon and tell the renderer which parts of the texture belong onto that polygon.

If you would like to do this, then the exact steps depend on the 3d modeling program you are using.

Comment: @FinnWilliams There are plenty of tutorials available for texturizing in Blender, including [the official manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/uv_image/index.html). If you have any questions you can't answer yourself, then you can look on https://blender.stackexchange.com